# Spark Streaming passing query parameters to Neo4j Scala

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, cypher, spark-streaming

I am trying to execute a Cypher query using a Spark-Neo4j connector. I want to pass the parameters into this query from the stream of data produced by Kafka. And the result of the Cypher query should be displayed as data frame fields. The connection with Neo4j is successfully established and my query works fine with simple spark context. However, the same code doesn't work for streaming context. Is there some difference with Neo4j connection configuration while using Spark Streaming?

Here is the code for streaming context. I do not use Kafka as producer here and the data for parameters is defined in data array for testing the connection and query itself:

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("KafkaSparkStreaming")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    val neo4jLocalConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("configs/local_neo4j.conf"))

    sparkSession.conf.set("spark.neo4j.bolt.url", neo4jLocalConfig.getString("neo4j.url"))
    sparkSession.conf.set("spark.neo4j.bolt.user", neo4jLocalConfig.getString("neo4j.user"))
    sparkSession.conf.set("spark.neo4j.bolt.password", neo4jLocalConfig.getString("neo4j.password"))

    val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkSession.sparkContext, Seconds(3))

    val neo = Neo4j(streamingContext.sparkContext)
    val data = Array("18731", "41.84000015258789", "-87.62999725341797")

    val query = "MATCH (m:Member)-[mtg_r:MT_TO_MEMBER]->(mt:MemberTopics)-[mtt_r:MT_TO_TOPIC]->(t:Topic), (t1:Topic)-[tt_r:GT_TO_TOPIC]->(gt:GroupTopics)-[tg_r:GT_TO_GROUP]->(g:Group)-[h_r:HAS]->(e:Event)-[a_r:AT]->(v:Venue) WHERE mt.topic_id = gt.topic_id AND distance(point({ longitude: {lon}, latitude: {lat}}),point({ longitude: v.lon, latitude: v.lat })) < 4000 AND mt.member_id = {id} RETURN distinct g.group_name as group_name, e.event_name as event_name, v.venue_name as venue_name"



    val paramsMap = Map("lat" -> data(1).toDouble, "lon" -> data(2).toDouble, "id" -> data(0).toInt)

    val df = neo.cypher(query, paramsMap).loadDataFrame("group_name" -> "string", "event_name" -> "string", "venue_name" -> "string")
    df.show()

    streamingContext.start()
    streamingContext.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by providing SparkConfig with required parameters for Neo4j to the SparkSession. Here is the code:

```
val config = "neo4j_local"
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("KafkaSparkStreaming")
    sparkConf.set("spark.neo4j.bolt.url", neo4jLocalConfig.getString("neo4j.url"))
        sparkConf.set("spark.neo4j.bolt.user", neo4jLocalConfig.getString("neo4j.user"))

    val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .config(sparkConf)
      .getOrCreate()
```